# Sort by custom field (acf) date picker and publish date

Tags: sorting, date

I would like to sort posts using firstly the custom field date picker by ACF plugin for wordpress, and then when that's non existing, by the published date.

Our theme works with cases so I cooked up something like this but I failed misearbly, any suggestions ?

```
        case 'concertdatum':
     $wp_query_args['meta_query'] =     array(        
    'relation' => 'AND',
    'datum_clause' => array(
        'meta_key' => 'datum',
        'meta_type' => 'DATETIME'
    ),
    'publish_clause' => array(
        'column' => 'post_date_gmt',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ), 
)
$wp_query_args['order'] = array(
    'datum_clause' => 'DESC',
    'publish_clause' => 'DESC'
);


        break;
```